# ¿Cómo puedo hacer ping a una IP con un valor dado?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

¿Cómo puedo hacer ping a cada uno de las ips de un arreglo? Ya lo intenté pero no me deja hacerlo alguien sabe como podria hacerlo sin que tenga algun error de compilacion y que pueda el usuario ingresar cada una de las ips

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float m[100];
    float n[100];
    int x;
    cout<<"ingrese tamaño:";
    cin>>x;
    for (int i=0;i<x;i++){
        
        cout<<"ingrese ["<<i+1<<"] valor :";
        cin>>m[i];
        n[i]=m[i];
        
    }
    
    stringstream comando;
    comando << "ping " <<n;
    
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
        
        system(comando.str().c_str()); 

     }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: la herramienta ping está pensada para recibir direcciones ip o nombres DNS ... ¿qué es eso de hacer ping a un número flotante?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ¿Cómo puedo hacer ping a una matriz de números flotantes en c++?

No puedes.

1. **No se puede hacer ping a matrices**: Las matrices son colecciones de datos. En todo caso podrás hacer ping a cada uno de los datos de la matriz, pero no a la matriz.
2. **No se puede hacer ping a números en coma flotante**: El comando [ping](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ping) espera una URL o una dirección IP. Un número en coma flotante no es ni lo uno ni lo otro.

Comment: ¿PaperBirdMaster como puedo hacer ping a una matriz de ips con con c++?

Answer (score 0):

hola lo que quería es hacer el siguiente código pero que funcione, lo que no entendía en ese momento era que en una variable `float` no se podían guardar direcciones IP de tipo `string` y menos que `system` lo unico que aceptaba era objetos de tipo `const char *` y que para eso era el metodo .`c_str()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <array>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    int numero;
    string puntero;

    cout<<"[+] Ingrese el numero de direcciones IP que desea ingresar al sistema:"<<'\n';
    cin>>numero;

    vector<string> direcciones(numero);

    for (int i = 0; i <= numero ; i++){

        
        cout<<"ingrese ["<<i+1<<"] Direccion IP :";

        cin>>direcciones[i];
        
     }
    
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i <= numero; i++){

        puntero = direcciones[i];
        cout<<puntero<<'\n';
        
        system(puntero.c_str()); 

     }
    return 0;
}
```